# How do I get MVC4 Web API to support HTTP Verbs and "Action" methods in the same controller?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

How do I setup routing to support this?

- GET /api/values/  **works**
- GET /api/values/1  **works**
- POST /api/values **works**
- PUT /api/values  **works**
- DELETE /api/values **works**
- GET /api/values/GetSomeStuff/1  **DOES NOT WORK!**

If I switch the routes around, then GetSomeStuff works, but then /api/values does not work.  How do I configure route to have them both work?

Example methods:

```
 // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetSomeStuff(int id)
    {
        return "stuff";
    }
```

Routes are setup like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: I used separate controllers (http://mangoit.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/rest-and-rpc-in-asp-net-web-api/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following routes:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultController",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9]*$" }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultController2",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id2}"
        );
```

and change your action method to:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetSomeStuff(int id2)
    {
        return "stuff";
    }
```

Comment: Yes, we did solve this with route constraints such as what you mention in your answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of:

```
GET /api/values/GetSomeStuff/1
```

you designed your urls like that:

```
GET /api/someStuff/1
```

Now you could simply have a `SomeStuffController` and a `Get(int id)` action on it.

Comment: is the only way is to have separate controllers for each one of these?  Should each controller only have 5 methods to be truly RESTful?

Comment: Facing a similar problem...is this correct, one controller has 5 methods only?